# log4net AdoNetAppender with bufferSize>1 and a pattern containing "aspnet-session"

Tags: log4net

I'm using log4net in a ASP.NET MVC application. I want to log to the database and am using AdoNetAppender with a bufferSize=10 to reduce the load on the database.

I also want to capture some session variables e.g. username. I can do this with a pattern like so:

```
%aspnet-session{username}
```

The problem is that the session values seem to be evaluated when the buffer is filled, not when the entry is logged, so I get 10 log entries with the same username even through each log entry was created by a different user.

This problem also effects calculated properties - i.e. the calculated property is evaluated when the buffer is filled, not when the entry is loggedd.

This is not a problem if bufferSize=1 because each log entry is logged, evaluated and written at the same time.

Is there a way to evaluate the session variables when the item is logged and buffer the log entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`Application_PostAcquireRequestState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postacquirerequeststate.aspx), set the username via the ThreadContext:

```
protected void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Make sure there's a Session in this request if you need it
     if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState)
     {
         var username = Session["UserName"];
         log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["username"] = username ;
     }
}
```

Then, in your config file you have this:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{username}" />
</layout>
```

Comment: Does this work if the thread where the log call is made has finished before the buffer is full?

Comment: Yes, the property is evaluated when the log event is generated.